# TFS branching and merging of MVC solution made up of several projects

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, tfs

We have a MVC/C# solution that is a made up of a number of projects (Data, Service, Model etc).
It started life in TFS saved in one DEV branch. We then made a Main branch and put this project into Main.
We then created a new DEV branch (task-1271) from Main so that we could perform some enhancements. This was released and merged back into Main.
We then created a new DEV branch (task-1316) for a further set of enhancements. I noticed that the Data project was pointing to the Data project dll (debug/bin folder) in previous DEV branch (task-1271). This caused problems as it would not pick up model changes when I ran a migration. After a lot of stress we eventually got it to pick up the model changes for the migration. Now I'm reluctant to check the project in to DEV as it seems to be still pointing back to the previous task folder. I don't want to update two DEV branches (if that's what will happen).

Is this not going to happen every time we merge back to Main? It's going to have references in some shape or form to previous DEV branch folders? Is there a flaw in this TFS strategy? Are there steps that should be carried out when merging and 
 DEV branching the solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Jason, any update on this? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that RickC suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

@Jason, I would strongly suggest that files (e.g., dlls) that are a product of building your c# project should ***not*** be checked into your version control system (VCS). This is considered a best practice when using *any* VCS. See [Version Control Concepts and Best Practices](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/advice/version-control.html) by Michael Ernst, particularly the section titled **Don't commit generated files**.

Your best bet here is to remove the DLL files from your VCS entirely. The general idea would be to check out the latest copy of any branch containing generated files, delete them all and then commit or check-in the branch.

Another thing that is important is to use a carefully-designed flow for branching and merging with your VCS. There is a lot of discussion of this topic on the web and people tend to be opinionated about their favorite VCS flow model. Two very popular models you might want to consider are Gitflow and GitHubflow.

For Gitflow, I recommend Vincent Driessen's original post, [A successful Git branching model](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) or Atlassian [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)).

For GitHub Flow, I would start with GitHub's guide [Understanding the GitHub flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/)).

Comment: Cheers RickC, will take a look.